# Why does sodium bicarbonate taste salty?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, taste

I just made myself sodium bicarbonate solution to treat heartburn. I never did this before, I rarely suffer from this condition.

What surprised me is how salty did the solution taste. I thought there is no similarity between table salt and baking soda. Yet they taste almost the same it seems.

Why is that?

Comment: Table salt is $\ce{NaCl}$ and sodium bicarbonate is $\ce{NaHCO3}$ so then what gives the "salty" taste?

Comment: @Hexacoordinate-C So it's something with sodium?

Comment: It should be related don't you think?

Comment: [Related](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/17038/why-does-salt-dissolved-in-water-taste-like-salt-if-its-just-na-and-cl-ions)

Comment: Due to the fact that the link from @Hexacoordinate-C basically answers the question, I am voting the question to be closed

Comment: Hmm, this:  https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/19662/9961 is better answer, but feel both questions aren't good duplicates.